# Cordova remote image not loading in https (android)

Tags: android, cordova

My application contain remote images, it works fine on IOS all images are loaded correctly.

On android on the other hand, image loaded with https are not working, but those with http are.
The issue happen only in production build, when in debug all image are loading correctly.

I thought it could be related to a non valide ssl certificate, but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: When https doesn't work in production builds it's because of server certificate problems

Comment: Even though there is a valid ssl certificat according to my browsers (tried with chrome and firefox), there was indeed an issue with the intermediate certificate which is probably why the images arent loaded

Comment: @mloret what was the issue in the certificate?